# Mysql InnoDB Disabled

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have modified the `my.cnf` for a MySQL 5 installation and now I receive the following error in `syslog`:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

I have removed the lines from `my.cnf` one by one and found the error prone lines are:

```
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
```

I don't see how specifying 256M limit is stopping a `5M` file working.

Does anyone know what causes this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

Add these lines to `/etc/my.cnf` (depending on your installation `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`)

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

then, do this:

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start --innodb-fast-shutdown=0
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you need to follow the proper documented method of [Resizing a log file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-and-removing.html).